# Change View position

Tags: java, android, layout, view, position

My View is not generated programmatically, but it is found with findbyid function. After getting view I like to position it properly.

To do that I am using [layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function to change position of view in onCreate with given parameters. Problem is that is not working properly and view stays in top left corner.

Function works fine while using it onTouch after activity is loaded. What I am doing wrong, is there another to set view based on these four parameters that [layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) uses.

Edit:

Params are loaded from DB.
this is what I use in onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.baseview);

View view=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blah);      

int top=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallerViewDB.TOP));
int bottom=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallerViewDB.BOTTOM));
int left=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallerViewDB.LEFT));
int right=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallerViewDB.RIGHT));
view.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Loaded values are right, checked it w sqllite browser. It seems that calling layout function in onCreate does not anything. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You need to add some code for us to figure out your problem.

Comment: Everyone could get more idea if you put a mock up screen shot of the layout your trying to get. Can't really figure that out from your code. As Ollie said, most things can be done in xml but it may vary based on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thing is I am loading basic ImageViews form xml, then user can position them in ParentView after which position are saved. Also user can reedit saved view. So again view is loaded form xml and positioned with values saved before.

Comment: FWIW `view.layout()` method seems to work when called from `onTouch()`, but will not work the way you are calling it (from my experience which led me to this page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after some reasearch this is how it is done:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parms.leftMargin=left;
parms.rightMargin=right;
parms.topMargin=top;
parms.bottomMargin=bottom;
view.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: this works, however i'm wondering why layout() doesn't work. Whether we need a invalidate() to force it re-layout?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 onPreDraw: Callback method to be invoked when the view tree is about to be
 drawn. At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a
 frame. Clients can use this to adjust their scroll bounds or even to request
 a new layout before drawing occurs.
*/

ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
OnPreDrawListener onPreDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw()
    {
        view.layout(....);
        return true;
    }
};
viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(onPreDrawListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea in most scenario. Android devices vary in screen size, orientation and resolution. It is recommended that you do not use absolute positioning, and instead using relative positioning.

Read up on RelativeLayout, and I'm sure it will do what you need.

Comment: Number which I have are get based on screen specifics. I just want to load them up on recreating view. RelativeLayout it self does not have anything specific to place view in position that i want and did save before.

Comment: OP states the user drags a view to a specific place. This is not the use case for `RelativeLayout`.