# How to update view position after view.layout() method?

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I'm trying to set position to view at activity start.

I found out that the most of my problems was about getting layout coordinates in onCreate method, so I wrote it in onWindowFocusChanged, coordinates aren't 0s, so I now can set position of view with layout() method.

I did it, but view didn't update its position. By the way, in my log view has new position.

I think there is a method which should update view, give me a hint, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW `view.layout()` method seems to work when called from `onTouch()`, but will not work the way you are calling it (from my experience which led me to this page)

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217614/change-view-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get layout params by using `getLayoutParams()` and the change margin then again set layout param.

1. `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = View.getLayoutParams();`
2. set margins in your param according to your new position.
3. `View.setLayoutParams(param)`.

If it is not solving your problem then please respond me so that I can try something else

Comment: Can I do this for FrameLayout?

Comment: I have not tried but it should because all layouts implement Viewgroup.layoutparam so it should be...